# Browser send the OPTIONS request does not bring the cookie to the server?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, cookies, cors

In Angularjs `config` file.

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
})
```

The application using the `Angularjs` on `front-end,`using `Spring MVC` on `backend`. When user login the application, the backend write the `session` to the `front-end`. So the application using the cookie to auth.

The `GET` and `POST` request all both ok. But there is a request which method using the "`PUT`", the browser send a request which's method is "`OPTIONS`". At that time,the server can't auth the request. Because there is no cookie. So browser send the "`OPTIONS`" request, it can bring the `cookie` to `Server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that your server treats OPTIONS requests separately and doesn't run them through the usual filters (assuming you're using a Java-based back-end). But make sure that the CORS filter adds all the Allow-* headers to their respective responses.

These requests should be treated as unauthenticated, meaning that they don't require credentials, aren't tied to a specific session and most importantly don't set any cookies that can affect your session.

> Because of session ID mismatch, CORS filter blocks the requests.

This is a misconception. CORS is agnostic to any user session. It's your server authentication logic that's blocking the request due to the newly created session ID which is invalid.

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34640755/3279156